# Xcode stuck on copying cache files from device tvOS

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I've been trying to connect my Apple TV with Xcode and it got stuck on copying cache files from device. It was connecting before as usual but suddenly it stopped.

**Version Information**

Apple TV : tvOS 13.4.6(17L570)
Xcode : 11.5 (11E608c)
macOS: 10.15.4 (19E287)

**What I've tried so far?**

- Clean build folder and rebuild
- Remove derived data
- Pairing and unpairing Apple TV thousand times
- Updated MacOS to latest version
- Reset Apple TV Couple of times
- Uninstall / Install Xcode again

> APP is busy: Copying cache files from device
> Xcode will continue when APP is finished.

[image: This is where it's stucked]

Answer (score 8):

Had this issue with iPhone SE, rather than AppleTV, and found only this question in my searches.

Ended up that I simply had to wait (very impatiently) with ***Xcode active on my Mac screen, and keeping the iPhone awake/unlocked***, for it to finish. Felt like forever, but it was less than 30 minutes in the end.

It seemed to stop the process if I moved off of Xcode to work on something else, or if the iPhone screen locked. So, keeping Xcode as the active app and keeping the iPhone awake *seemed* to allow the process to finally finish.

Comment: Had the same issue with an iPhone SE (2020), took about 5 mins total to finish.

Comment: I experience the same issue with iPhone SE. I waited for 1h 20 min, in the end I gave up

Comment: I simply waited for it to finish. After about 5 minutes, it wrapped it up. I did quit and restart Xcode, so, not sure if that had an impact. I still had to wait 5 minutes after the quit and restart of Xcode. Mine was with iPad.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I just restarted my device and restart Xcode. No more waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you open the devices window you can see the error results the hang issue. in my case it was that Xcode version was too low than the devices version.

Closed Xcode updated it and it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, detaching and re-attaching the device solved the issue.
No need to wait for x mins...

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you did. All of that and even more. Nothing helped. Also i tried to bring router, appleTV and macbook together physically, and that did not helped too. I left them for two hours. There are the result: 6 errors with detail description:

```
Details

Unable to copy symbols from this device
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -1
Failure Reason: Xcode was unable to read the required data from the device
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011eb85645 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011eb8b358 DTDKGetSharedCacheFileSync + 4681
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011eb8d4ba __DTDKCopySharedCacheFiles_block_invoke_4 + 4641
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105b5de14 __43-[DVTDispatchLock asyncPerformLockedBlock:]_block_invoke + 40
    4   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105b847f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105b86be9 __DVTDispatchBarrierAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efd26c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efd3658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efd8c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efd9609 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 414
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efd56d0 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 86
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efd4f16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efe1957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6efe2097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6f2319f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6f230b77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E266)
Xcode 11.5 (16139)
```

[image]

#### Solution:

Go to `AppleTV -> Settings -> Main (Основное) -> Storage (Управление хранилищем)` and remove all apps. Or you can remove some of them one by one and try to build every time. After removing some games and small not famous apps the xcode come work with AppleTV!

Next morning i started to connect Xcode and AppleTV4K again and the issue appeared again. I reloaded router and waited for 5 minutes. After that it works.

**Note:**
If your wifi connection is not stable - it can be a long time while symbols would copy. So as the additional step - upgrade your wifi router. And be ready to wait 20 min.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Removing all apps and reseting device helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I Quit and start my Xcode again, this got fixed. In some cases updating Xcode can be required.

Comment: I've restart Xcode and that thing helped me. Probably delete Derived Data also could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work without having to wait the 30 minutes.  I changed my lock phone to never.  I ran my code in the iOS 12 simulator.  I rebooted my phone.  I brought up devices and simulators, and it said my phone was ready with a solid globe, so I unplugged my cable.  Changed from simulator to my device.  Ran it, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to happen to me when I updated my iOS version. The solution was to remove the app from device and rebuild from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarted Xcode and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode, restarting your iPhone or iPad, and allowing a few minutes for things to settle can indeed help in resolving your issues.

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me:

> Have you tried clearing derived data?
>
> At the top: Xcode, Preferences, locations, derived data. Click the little arrow to enter into Finder.
>
> Wipe the folders inside of derived data out, rebuild

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/j1hsl3/copying_cache_files_from_device/g6zvj4f?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3